# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found When working with JavaFX in vscode

Tags: java, json, javafx, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use vscode to work in JavaFX (I'm on macOS if it makes any difference), and no matter what when I try to run my code it gives me this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer 
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

This only happens when I have these vmArgs in the launch.json file:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path /javafx/lib/src/javafx.controls --add-modules javafx.controls"
```

If I don't have those vmArgs in the json, I get this error instead:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.
```

What should I do to get this to run? Why is it not recognizing that I have referenced the javafx.controls module in my json but yet when I don't have it, I get another error? Any help would be appreciated because I really have no clue which direction to take here.

Comment: Is the javafx.controls module in the location you have specified in your vmArgs `/javafx/lib/src/javafx.controls`, and is that parth correct relative to your application? Have you included all the javaFX dependencies in your library folder?

Comment: Try this: `--module-path /javafx/lib/src/javafx.controls.jar`

Answer (score 0):

you path is wrong, You must specify the path of your folder and in the modules load the module you need, ej

"vmArgs": "--module-path */javafx/lib/src/javafx.controls* change for
"vmArgs": "--module-path /javafx/lib/src/ --add-modules javafx.controls